# how you can change the style of the page without changing CSS files?

Tags: css, html, browser, web

How would you go about changing the appearance of a website say when demonstrating a website to a client without going directly into the css files and editing it.

For the purpose of an interactive styling session when as a customer we need little tweaks to the site as its in discussion.

Comment: You can add all the CSS classes that you need (regular and demo) to the stylesheet and then use jquery to replace classes as needed.

Comment: Either `style` in the `head` or inline styling.. `style="..."` .. Additionally, you could also add CSS styling via the dev tool (F12)

Comment: There are some nice extensions for Google Chrome which can change the styles directly in the browser. I am not sure if any of these actually support persistency, but it should definitely be possible.

Comment: `<style>` tags and `style="..."` tag attributes.

Comment: There is no way you could write a script to edit all possible variables a client may want changing... You would be better doing it in a graphics package like Photoshop, gimp etc and amending web page code afterwards.

Comment: If you are using a modern browser then you should be able to edit the styles using the console (F12 in chrome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a better way than using the [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles)

> Web Inspector
>
> The Web Inspector gives you quick and easy access to the richest set
>   of development tools ever included in a browser. From viewing the
>   structure of a page to debugging JavaScript to optimizing performance,
>   the Web Inspector presents its tools in a clean window designed to
>   make developing web applications more efficient. To activate it,
>   choose Show Web Inspector from the Develop menu.

[Safari Web Inspector - Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW26)

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Common Browsers

- Safari - [Safari Web Inspector - Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/ResourcesandtheDOM/ResourcesandtheDOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH3-SW26)
- Chrome - [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles)
- Opera - [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

Comment: Wow. I never even knew this existed. How is it different than the built in Web Inspector in Safari?